# Format 16-digit number to 4-digit groups in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In my google spreadsheet, I store 16-digits numbers. For human readability, it's easier to show them as space-separated groups, like 1234 5678 9012 3456; at the same time, if I want to copy this number in order to paste somewhere else, it is better to have it without any spaces. So I thought the solution would be to keep it as a number and apply custom format "#### #### #### ####". The problem is when I apply this format, the last digit becomes zero - without even any warning! Any ideas? The only solution I have now is to make another cell which will convert the number (with some ugly formula like `=left(A1,4)&" "&mid(A1,5,4)&" "&mid(A1,9,4)&" "&right(A1,4)`) to space-separated string...

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is when I apply this format, the last digit becomes zero -
>   without even any warning!

That is because the nimber is too big for Google sheets, see more info here:

https://superuser.com/questions/602810/how-can-i-use-extremely-large-numbers-in-my-spreadsheet-programs

I suggest:

1. Keep the number in cells formatted as plain text.
2. Use some formulas to convert them into number with spaces.

You may try this formula too:

`=JOIN(" ",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,rept("(\d{4})",4)))`

Comment: yeah, I understand why that happens (although I still think it's really bad they don't give any warning when making this lossy conversion), I was just wondering if there's any way not to create another cell - unfortunately your solution also requires it. Thank you for the idea about regex though, it looks much better with it.